# Access SQL Update query did not update table

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I write a code to update to decrease some value from textbox like this
`Textbox4.Text with value = "5"`  to decrease `PRO_BALANCE` field in table
`Combobox2.Text with value = "30000"` That match the `PRO_ID` Field in the table

```
   Try
     Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WindowsApplication1.My.MySettings.DatabaseMobileConnectionString").ConnectionString
        'Dim con As New OleDbConnection(constr)
        'Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim cmdtext As String = "UPDATE  PRODUCT" & _
                              " SET       PRO_BALANCE = PRO_BALANCE -?" & _
                              " WHERE  (PRO_ID = ?)"
      Using con As New OleDbConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(cmdtext, con)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@pro_Balance", OleDbType.SmallInt).Value = Val(TextBox4.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pro_ID", OleDbType.SmallInt).Value = Val(ComboBox2.Text)
                con.Open()
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

it's nothing happened field PRO_BALANCE Remain the same not decrease

```
PRO_ID      PRO_BALANCE
30000       50
```

it would be

```
PRO_ID      PRO_BALANCE
30000       45
```

Comment: It might have to do with your data types.  `OleDbType.SmallInt` maps to Int16 so THAT Id is on the verge of overflowing it.  Also using Val returns a Double so you have a data conversion going on there.  Also, get rid of the empty Try/Catch - you are swallowing any and all errors the code may report

Answer (score 0):

It's possible there is another connection blockning writes to you're database.

Make sure any process that could have an open connection to the database is closed.